# webservice calculate sum in console app?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, soap

Not sure if anyone will be able to understand this but here is the code:

```
        case 1:
        double[] myArrai1 = new double[3];
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGray;
        Console.WriteLine("*-------------------------------------------------------* ");
        Console.WriteLine("*  Enter an array of numbers to get the sum total       * ");
        Console.WriteLine("*-------------------------------------------------------* ");
        Console.WriteLine("Insert a number");
        myArrai1[0] = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Insert a number");
        myArrai1[1] = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Insert a number");
        myArrai1[2] = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        DrawStarLine();
        foreach (double d in myArrai1)
        Console.WriteLine( d );
        Webservices09004961.ServiceReference1.CalculateSumRequest array = new ServiceReference1.CalculateSumRequest();
        //ServiceReference1.CalculateSumRequest array = new ServiceReference1.CalculateSumRequest();
        Webservices09004961.ServiceReference1.ArrayOfDouble arrayOfDoubles = new Webservices09004961.ServiceReference1.ArrayOfDouble(); 
        //CalculateSumOfList.ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient client = new CalculateSumOfList.ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient();
        //CalculateSumOfList.ServiceReference1.ArrayOfDouble arrayOfDoubles = new CalculateSumOfList.ServiceReference1.ArrayOfDouble();
        arrayOfDoubles.AddRange(myArrai1);
        double e = array.CalculateSum(arrayOfDoubles); //error on this line CalculateSum?
        Console.WriteLine("=" + e);
        Console.ReadLine();
        break;
```

I store 3 user input numbers in myArrai1 which I would like to "sum" to sum I have made a webreference CalculateSumOfList.

But It says my webreference does not contain CalculateSum in my webservice, yet it does and im using it in windows forms within the same build/project?

Thanks.

Comment: That makes perfect sense (to me at least as I'm doing not dissimilar things) - but to help we'll need to know what the error is...

Comment: namespace error, missing directive. The code was from a windows form app but I cant see how to call and create an array of doubles with the webreference?

Comment: This may well be because I have two webreferences im not sure? double f = client.ConvertTemp(tempC, Convert.TemperatureUnit.degreeCelsius, Convert.TemperatureUnit.degreeFahrenheit);

Comment: Cleaned the code up and the question abit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So with some trial and error I had realised I was calling client the first time round which was already used for another webservice.

```
    case 1:
        double[] myArrai1 = new double[3];
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGray;
        Console.WriteLine("*-------------------------------------------------------* ");
        Console.WriteLine("*  Enter an array of numbers to get the sum total       * ");
        Console.WriteLine("*-------------------------------------------------------* ");
        Console.WriteLine("Insert a number");
        myArrai1[0] = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Insert a number");
        myArrai1[1] = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Insert a number");
        myArrai1[2] = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        DrawStarLine();
        foreach (double d in myArrai1)
        Console.WriteLine( d );
        Webservices09004961.ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient client2 = new ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient();
        Webservices09004961.ServiceReference1.ArrayOfDouble arrayOfDoubles = new Webservices09004961.ServiceReference1.ArrayOfDouble(); 
        arrayOfDoubles.AddRange(myArrai1);
        string e = client2.CalculateSum(arrayOfDoubles);
        Console.WriteLine("=" + e);
        Console.ReadLine();
        break;
```

So to sum it up (no pun intended) I could have spent 5 hours watching and reading tutorials or just used abit of trial and error with the help of SO!